# Why when I minimize the window shapes move in html?

Tags: html, css, web, shapes

I'm trying to put an octagon inside of another octagon, but the thing is that when I minimize the screen of my web browser, the shapes move, I hope you could help me with this problem because I dn't understand why this happens, thanks in advance

```css
.octagonWrap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
  }
  
  .octagonWrapTwo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 270px;
    left: 241px;
  }
  
  .octagon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  .octagontwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  .octagon:before {
    position: absolute;
    /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
       * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
       * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
       */
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: '';
    border: inherit;
  }
  
  .octagontwo:before {
    position: absolute;
    /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
       * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
       * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
       */
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: '';
    border: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class='octagonWrap'>
        <div class='octagon'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='octagonWrapTwo'>
        <div class='octagontwo'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is the code showed in the snippet, if someone would recommend me something I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of the percentages

```
.octagonWrap {
    ...
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
  }
```

if the screen is 1000px, top will be 100px, if the screen is 2000px, the top will be 200px.

if they're specific numbers/pixels the position will stay the same. essentially.

Comment: so should I delete that?

Comment: Try, changing 10% to 20px. Try changing 20% to 40px. Or whatever number of pixels works best.